# ES7 - ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse date field [1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28] with format [dateTime]

Tags: elasticsearch

```
ERROR [2023-08-07 17:18:11,656] fk.sp.fulfilment.apollo.common.exceptions.TemplateException: Runtime exception caught! Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[TuXIUIUtSG2nBgh7WkrgkQ][shipment_actionable_v2][57]: RemoteTransportException[[10.52.103.228][10.52.103.228:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse date field [1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28] with format [dateTime]: [failed to parse date field [1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28] with format [dateTime]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to parse date field [1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28] with format [dateTime]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[date_time_parse_exception: Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers]; }
```

**Context:**

```
{
    "params": {
        "dispatch_tiers": ["REGULAR", "EXPRESS"],
        "seller_id": "7052a23b7cbe4f36",
        "location_id": "LOC65e341d6660f443c8dc5ffd085d5740b",
        "order_date": {
            "from": "1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:30",
            "to": "2023-08-07T06:46:49.000+05:30"
        },
        // Other parameters
    },
    // Other sections of the template
}
```

`response = new SearchTemplateRequestBuilder(client) .setRequest(searchRequest) .setScript(templateName) .setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED) .setScriptParams(params) .get() .getResponse();`

`While running the ES query we are getting the response with dateTime format, but when using this template with api, it giving the issue.`
`{ "range": { "units.order_date": { "from": "1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28", "to": "2023-08-07T06:46:49.000+05:30", "include_lower": true, "include_upper": true } }`

In the process of executing the Elasticsearch query within the template, I am obtaining a response with the dateTime format. However, when this template is employed in conjunction with an API request, the aforementioned error surfaces.

Comment: Because your `from` date is not correct. it should be `1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:30` and not `1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28`. it should be `+05:30` in the end of date.

Comment: Agreed with Sagar, time zones don't have a seconds position

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented, it is issue with timezone value passed in `from` date. it should be `1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:30` and not `1682-12-06T01:31:43.000+05:53:28`.

it should be `+05:30` in the end of date.